# SQL Server Query - Missing Data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, case, aggregate

I have an issue with data being excluded from my query results -

```
select 
    D.[Date], D.MonthName, D.WeekOfYear, 
    E.bu_name, E.emp_mgr, E.emp_sup, E.emp_name, E.emp_jde, 
    C.Calls, S.sales
from 
    DATE TABLE As D
join 
    (Select 
         cast([start_date] as date) as call_date, [agent_no], 
         sum(case when [skill_name] like '5700 Sales l%' and [Agent_Time] != '0' then 1 else 0 end) as calls
     from 
         CALL TABLE
     group by 
         cast([start_date] as date), [agent_no]) As C on D.[Date] = C.call_date
join 
    (Select 
         [AC#DTE_dt] As sale_date, [EMPJDENUM], 
         sum(case when [CH]='I' and ([IC]='L' or [IC]='H') and [ITMQTY]>3 and [EMPBUNCOD] in ('5044', '5077', '5169', '5178', '5179', '5186', '5187', '5189', '5190') then 1 else 0 end) as sales
     from 
         SALE TABLE
     group by 
         [AC#DTE_dt], [EMPJDENUM]) As S on D.Date = s.sale_date
join 
    EMPLOYEE TABLE As E on C.[agent_no] = E.[emp_vcc]
                        and S.[EMPJDENUM] = E.emp_jde
                        and S.sale_date between E.start_date and E.end_date
where 
    D.[Date] = '11/5/2016'
```

**Results**

[image]

If both the call or sales subquery tables have a match to the employees table as defined in the join on the Employee table at the bottom of the query - aggregates from the sum(case when will be returned.  If for whatever reason, there is no data to join off of in the call or sales subquery, the row is excluded.  What I want is for the result to return 0 or null.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you just need to specify when there is an OUTER join, and where you are doing an INNER join

```
select 
    D.[Date], D.MonthName, D.WeekOfYear, 
    E.bu_name, E.emp_mgr, E.emp_sup, E.emp_name, E.emp_jde, 
    C.Calls, S.sales
    from 
    DATE TABLE As D
LEFT OUTER join 
    (Select 
     cast([start_date] as date) as call_date, [agent_no], 
     sum(case when [skill_name] like '5700 Sales l%' and [Agent_Time] != '0' then 1 else 0 end) as calls
 from 
     CALL TABLE
 group by 
     cast([start_date] as date), [agent_no]) As C on D.[Date] = C.call_date
LEFT OUTER join 
    (Select 
     [AC#DTE_dt] As sale_date, [EMPJDENUM], 
     sum(case when [CH]='I' and ([IC]='L' or [IC]='H') and [ITMQTY]>3 and [EMPBUNCOD] in ('5044', '5077', '5169', '5178', '5179', '5186', '5187', '5189', '5190') then 1 else 0 end) as sales
 from 
     SALE TABLE
 group by 
     [AC#DTE_dt], [EMPJDENUM]) As S on D.Date = s.sale_date
INNER join 
EMPLOYEE TABLE As E on C.[agent_no] = E.[emp_vcc]
                    and S.[EMPJDENUM] = E.emp_jde
                    and S.sale_date between E.start_date and E.end_date
where 
D.[Date] = '11/5/2016'
```